# How can I forbit editing webix select fields using view: "combo"?

Tags: javascript, webix

**This is piece of my js file**

How can I forbit editing webix select fields using view: "combo"? Using view: "select" is not an option.

```
rows: [          {
                    borderless: true,
                    css: "font_bold",
                    height: 35,
                    template: displayContent
                  },
                  {
                    view: "combo",
                    id: "myId",
                    tooltip: somevalue,
                    value: someid,
                    options: contactListOptions,
                    on: {
                     ------
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was mentioned at [their forum](http://forum.webix.com/discussion/6901/combo-showing-single-option-popup-while-readonly-in-os-x)

I've tested a bit - seems like it still works the same way, so the following workaround is relevant:

```
/* if readonly set to true */
  suggest:{        
    on:{  
      onBeforeShow:function(){
        var parent = $$(this.config.master);
        if (parent.config.readonly)
          return false; 
      }
    },    
    body:{ 
      on:{
        onBeforeSelect:function(){
          var parent = $$(this.getParentView().config.master);          
          if (parent.config.readonly)               
            return false;
        }
      }
    },
    data:combo_data,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use richselect editor, which behaves the same as combo, but doesn't allow edit operations.

```
 {
   view: "richselect",
   id: "myId",
   tooltip: somevalue,
   value: someid,
   options: contactListOptions,
   on: { /**/ }
 }
```